# React functional component static property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I had a class component with another class component as his static property.
Now I switched to a function component and I don't know how to keep the static property.

```
class Panel extends React.Component<Props> {
  public static Fieldset = PanelFieldset;
}

class PanelFieldset extends React.Component<Props> {
  ...
}

class App extends React.Component<Props> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Panel>
        <Panel.Fieldset>
          ...
        </Panel.Fieldset>
      </Panel>
    )
  }
}
```

Now, switching to function component:

```
const Panel: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  Panel.Fieldset = PanelFieldset;
}
```

but I get the error:
Property 'Fieldset' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent'.ts(2339)

Any help?

Comment: I hope this helps! https://www.reactandtypescript.dev/examples/functional-components#functional-components-with-static-properties

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**With implicit typing (Best Solution)**

The following shows an apporach where you don't have to type your static properties explicitly. I personally prefer this over any other solution, since it is the shortest and most clean way.

```
const PanelComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
 ...
}

export const Panel = Object.assign(PanelComponent, { PanelFieldset })
```

**With explicit typing (Previous Solution)**

If you want to type your static properties explicitly, extending @Andrew's answer, using `typeof PanelFieldset` should be more convenient to type your component.

```
type IPanel<P> = React.FunctionComponent<P> & {
  Fieldset: typeof PanelFieldset; // add this
}

const Panel: IPanel<Props> = (props) => {
}

Panel.Fieldset = PanelFieldset;
```

**Source:** https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Dropdown.tsx#L230-L237

Answer (score 21):

For `static` properties on a function you declare them on the function itself i.e.

```
function Panel() {
}
// static props
Panel.Fieldset = PanelFieldset
```

A similar approach can be seen for setting [propTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) on a component. I assume in TS that would look like:

```
Panel.Fieldset: React.Component<Props> = PanelFieldset
```

Comment: @JohnnyZabala I misread, I thought they had `Panel.Fieldset: PanelFieldset`, d'oh

Comment: Oh I see! Yeah, you are right in that case, it wouldn't be valid js.

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting the same error: Property 'Add' does not exist on type FunctionComponent

Comment: @SimoneConti that doesn't seem related? There is on `Add` property in the example given.

Comment: It is related. `React.Component<Props>` can only define keys inside `props`. `Fieldset` is a propery on the function itself, not inside props

Comment: @Andrew I don't use TS so not aware of where `Add` comes from

Comment: Thank you for this concise answer!

Answer (score 10):

`React.FunctionComponent` is scoped purely within the `key` `props`, which you discovered does not work when you want to add a property that is not in the `props` key. In order to properly type it, you need to make your own type and extend it.

After that, assign it outside of the function

```js
type IPanel<P> = React.FunctionComponent<P> & {
  Fieldset: any //whatever type it actually is
}

const Panel: IPanel<Props> = (props) => {
}

Panel.Fieldset = PanelFieldset;
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with:
const Panel: React.FunctionComponent<Props> & { PanelFieldset: React.FunctionComponent<PanelFieldsetProps> }

Comment: Quite a bit to put as an inline type, but I'm not going to tell you how to write your code ;). Glad it worked out, and good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 5):

Typescript compiler is telling you that you are using a property that is not defined in the function. Move `Panel.Fieldset = PanelFieldset;` outside de function.

```
// Bad
function A() {
  A.B = 'hello'
}

// Good
function A() {}
A.B = "Here we go."
```